# Bash function parameter assignment to read a file (list) and write a file (array)

Tags: bash, function, parameter-passing, filenames

I am trying to write a bash function I can call regularly from within a larger set of scripts. I want to pass this function the name of a file containing a plain list of text strings:

```
blue
red
green
```

... and have the function write out these strings to a different file (the name of which is also passed as parameter to the function) in bash-compatible array format:

```
[Bb]lue [Rr]ed [Gg]reen
```

I can't get the function to (internally) recognise the name of the output file being passed. It throws an "ambiguous redirect" error and then a bunch of "No such file or directory" errors after that. It is however processing the input file OK. The problem appears be how I am assigning the parameter to a local string in the function. Unfortunately I have changed the `loc_out=` line in the function so many times that I can no longer recall all the forms I have tried. Hopefully the example is clear, if not best practise:

```
process_list () {
    # assign input file name to local string
    loc_in=(${1});
    # assign output file name to local string
    loc_out=($(<${2})); # this is not right
    while read line
    do
        echo "loc_out before: $loc_out";
        echo "loc_in term: $line"; 
        item_length=${#line};
        # loop until end of string
        for (( i=0; i<$item_length; i++ )); 
        do 
            echo "char $i of $line: ${line:$i:1}"; 
            # write out opening bracket and capital
            if [ ${i} -eq 0 ]; then
                echo -e "[" >> $loc_out;
                echo -e ${line:$i:1} | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' >> "${loc_out}";
            fi;
            # write out current letter
            echo -e ${line:$i:1} >> "${loc_out}";
            # write out closing bracket
            if [ ${i} -eq 0 ]; then
                echo -e "]" >> "${loc_out}";
            fi;
        done;    
        # write out trailing space
        echo -e " " >> "${loc_out}";
        # check the output file
        echo "loc_out after: ${loc_out}";
    done < $loc_in;
}
f_in="/path/to/colour_list.txt";
f_out="/path/to/colour_array.txt";
echo "loc_in (outside function): ${loc_in}";
echo "loc_out (outside function): ${loc_out}";
process_list $f_in $f_out;
```

Any assistance on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$(<${2})` assuming $2 is a filename, this says to open the file and place all of the contents of the file at this point in your shell script. I don't think that's what you want to do. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter. I was getting confused between initially assigning the file handle at the head of the function and later echoing back the content of this file near the bottom of the function. Second last function line should read `echo "loc_out after: $(<${loc_out})";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
loc_out=($(<${2})); # this is not right
```

To this:

```
loc_out=(${2}); # this should be right
```

You want in that line just the file name.

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

EDIT:

Besides you could/should write this:

```
loc_in=${1};
loc_out=${2};
```

You do not need parantheses, as far as I understand.

Comment: Thank you. I was sure I tried that, but evidently not. There are a few other errors in my example that I evidently introduced while playing around with it i.e., the `echo` redirects to `$loc_out` should use `-ne` rather than `-e` and the open square bracket echo should have `"${loc_out}"`.